# Вывод содержимого при запуске

Tags: 1с

В 1С 8.3. Хочу при запуске 1С:Предприятие вывести в консоль содержимое Перечисления(Регистров, Справочников). Написал следующий код в разделе Общие

```
Модули:  
Процедура  Тест1()  
Типы = Перечисления.Типы;  
Для каждого тип из Типы цикл  
Сообщить(тип);  
КонецЦИкла  
КонецПроцедуры
```

Выдаётся ошибка, хотя на самом деле Перечисление Типы имеется в разделе Перечисления. Помогите, кто чем может.

В логе вижу ошибку:

> {ОбщийМодуль.ОбщийМодуль1.Модуль(2,9)}: Переменная не определена (Перечисления)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что у вашего общего модуля в свойствах стоит лишь флажок "Клиент". На клиенте менеджеры перечислений недоступны. Для того, чтобы ваш код заработал, нужно поставить общему модулю флажок "Сервер".